# Print de atributos de los objetos de un ArrayList

Tags: java, poo, arraylist, atributos

Quiero lanzar un printf de todos los atributos de los objetos que tengo dentro de un arrayList. Es decir tengo un Arraylist de objetos vehículo y quiero lanzar un printf de sus atributos; marca, matricula, descripción, km, ....
De momento el método que tengo para ello es:

```
    public void listarVehiculos() {
    
            Collections.sort(nombreArray);
            
            if (nombreArray.isEmpty()) {//Si aún no se han introducido vehículos entonces salta este mensaje
                System.out.println("No existe ningún vehículo aún.");
                return;
            }
    
            
            System.out.println("El concesionario contiene " + nombreArray.size()
 + " vehículos:\n");
            System.out.printf("%-12s\t%-15s\t%-9s\t%-12s\t%-8s\t%-32s\t%-8s\t%-38s\n","Numero","Marca","Matrícula","Precio","Km","Descripción","DNI","Propietario"); 
            
            for(int i=0; i<nombreArray.size(); i++){
                
               System.out.printf("%-12s\t%-15s\t%-9s\t%-9.2f\t%-8d\t%-32s\t%-8s\t%-38s\n",(i+1),nombreArray.get(i).getMarca(),nombreArray.get(i).getMatricula(), nombreArray.get(i).getPrecio(), 
                             nombreArray.get(i).getNumKm(),nombreArray.get(i).getDescripcion(),nombreArray.get(i).getDniPropietario(),nombreArray.get(i).getNombrePropietario());
                
            }
    
        }//fin metodo listarVehiculos
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando lo lanzo en eclipse no me devuelve el valor de los atritutos en la misma línea sino que me hace saltos de linea a pesar de que no he insertado ningun salto.
Sabría alguien recomendarme una forma mas adecuada de hacer la impresión que deseo

Comment: creo que tienes que desactivar en la consola de eclipse el "line wrapping"

Comment: Sobre-escribe el método `toString()` del objeto con el formato que mas te convenga. O crea un método que te regrese un HashMap con los atributos a mostrar, al imprimilo -el HashMap- te saldrá en una sola línea.